# CRM/XRM OrganizationServiceProxy and Microsoft.IdentityModel 3.5 / System.IdentityModel 4.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, dynamics-crm-2013, asp.net-4.5, xrm

From ASP.NET MVC (.NET 4.5) I connect to a CRM server with a OrganizationServiceProxy as follows:

```
private IOrganizationService GetCrmService(string userName, string password, string domain, Uri serviceUri)
        {
            OrganizationServiceProxy _serviceProxy;

            ClientCredentials credentials = new ClientCredentials();
            credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);
            ClientCredentials deviceCredentials = new ClientCredentials();

            using (_serviceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(serviceUri, null, credentials, deviceCredentials))
            {
                _serviceProxy.ServiceConfiguration.CurrentServiceEndpoint.Behaviors.Add(new ProxyTypesBehavior());
                return (IOrganizationService)_serviceProxy;
            }
        }
```

It all works fine on my development machine but when I deploy to my designated web server it fails with:

```
[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceConfiguration`1.CreateLocalChannelFactory() +0
   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceConfiguration`1.CreateChannelFactory(ClientCredentials clientCredentials) +290
   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceConfiguration.CreateChannelFactory(ClientCredentials clientCredentials) +16
   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceProxy`1.get_ChannelFactory() +126
   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceProxy`1.CreateNewServiceChannel() +24
   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceContextInitializer`1.Initialize(ServiceProxy`1 proxy) +31
   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceContextInitializer..ctor(OrganizationServiceProxy proxy) +54
   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy.RetrieveMultipleCore(QueryBase query) +892
```

I suppose activating the server feature "Windows Identity Foundation 3.5" would solve the issue, but I am told that this has all been replaced with the new WIF 4.5 classes which are part of the .NET 4.5 framework.

But I have no idea how to rewrite my code or make the changes necessary to make this switch.

Comment: Check the reference to Microsoft.IdentityModel in your project it should be set to CopyLocal = True. I think that's all that is required

Comment: Dynamics CRM libraries still use WIF 3.5, so you should install them

Comment: Installed WIF 3.5, referenced Microsoft.IdentityModel with CopyLocal = True. Thanks.